# How to start JBoss AS 7?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I run the standalone.bat

I encounter a page 404 error when accessing
`http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

May i know what is wrong?

Below is the server startup logs

```
Config file not found C:\software\JBoss\bin\standalone.conf.bat
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\software\JBoss

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat  -server

===============================================================================

20:10:34,077 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.0.0.Beta17
20:10:34,406 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.0.Beta8
20:10:34,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss AS 7.0.0.Beta3 "Salyut" starting
20:10:35,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] Activating core services
20:10:35,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as] creating native management service using netwo
rk interface (default) port (9999)
20:10:35,484 INFO  [org.jboss.as] creating http management service using network
 interface (default) port (9990)
20:10:35,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as.arquillian] Activating Arquillian Subsystem
20:10:35,515 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ee] Activating EE subsystem
20:10:35,577 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] Activating Naming Subsystem
20:10:35,781 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] Deploying JDB
C-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.2)
20:10:35,796 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] Activating OSGi Subsystem
20:10:36,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] Activating WebServices Extension
20:10:36,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] Removing bootstrap log handlers
20:10:36,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] Starting Naming Service
20:10:36,484 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Started Fi
leSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\software\JBoss\standalone\deployments

20:10:36,499 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC s
ervice thread 1-4) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.0.Alpha4
20:10:36,531 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting
version 3.1.0.Beta2
20:10:36,593 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jmx.JMXConnectorService] (MSC service thread 1-
1) Starting remote JMX connector
20:10:36,593 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener] (MSC service
thread 1-3) The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
 production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program File
s\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Tortois
eSVN\bin
20:10:36,609 WARN  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.URLHandlerPlugin] (MSC ser
vice thread 1-3) Unable to set the URLStreamHandlerFactory
20:10:36,609 WARN  [org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.URLHandlerPlugin] (MSC ser
vice thread 1-3) Unable to set the ContentHandlerFactory
20:10:36,749 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service
 thread 1-2) live server is starting..
20:10:36,765 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread
 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
20:10:36,984 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting JC
A Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.0.Beta5)
20:10:37,015 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service
thread 1-3) Bound JDBC Data-source [java:/H2DS]
20:10:37,124 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor] (MSC ser
vice thread 1-2) Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.1.Final-r2319 localhost:5445
 for CORE protocol
20:10:37,140 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptor] (MSC ser
vice thread 1-2) Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.1.Final-r2319 localhost:5455
 for CORE protocol
20:10:37,140 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service
 thread 1-2) HornetQ Server version 2.1.2.Final (Colmeia, 120) started
20:10:37,218 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss AS 7.0.0.Beta3
"Salyut" started in 3391ms - Started 100 of 147 services (47 services are passiv
e or on-demand)
```

Answer (score 8):

In the alphas and betas of JBoss 7 there were no welcome page deployed. There are and will be in the final release.

To get a page there simply deploy a war named ROOT.war or a war with / as its context root.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose that there is no web application that can be executed.

You can connect to console using these address: http://localhost:9990/console/.

Answer (score 4):

There's simply no default web page there. Try deploying your web app and accessing it.